# Assign a value to a variable at compilation time

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I'd like to assign a specific value to a variable when my code is compiling (for C and C++):

For example having :

```
//test.c
int main()
{
   int x = MYTRICK ; (edit: changed __MYTRICK__ to MYTRICK to follow advices in comment)
   printf ("%d\n", x);

   return 0;
}
```

beeing able to do something like:

```
gcc -XXX MYTRICK=44 test.c -o test
```

and having as a result :

```
$./test
44
```

Comment: See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html and look for -D option as **ouah** mention in his answer

Comment: Names starting with two underscores, or starting with underscore followed by uppercase, are reserved to the implementation.

Comment: You must never use double underscores, and also never use leading underscore-capitals in tokens. Those are *reserved*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `-D` option:

```
gcc -DMYTRICK=44 test.c -o test
```

And use `MYTRICK` macro in your program and not `__MYTRICK__`. Names beginning with `__` are reserved by the implementation.

Comment: Thank you !
(Actually it's "gcc -D__MYTRICK__=44 test.c -o test" regarding to my code)

Comment: You may want to put something like `#ifndef MYTRICK\n#define MYTRICK *default value*\n#endif` in your program so that it still compiles without a -D flag. (Or you might not.)

Comment: @IggY While there's little chance that using that reserved name will cause a problem, why not just do it right and call it, say, IGGYS_TRICK?

Comment: I edited my question to remove the double underscores, thank you for your precisions