# Will compiler -D flag take priority over code #define of macro variable?

Tags: compilation, macros, c-preprocessor

I have some testing code in Fortran which basically looks like

```
#define test1 0 
#define test2 0 
#define test3 0 

... 

#if test1
   call test1() 
#endif 

#if test2
   call test2() 
#endif 

#if test3 
   call test3() 
#endif 

...
```

At compilation, i want to change those values using -Dtest1=1.
I've seen some answers ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598287/assign-a-value-to-a-variable-at-compilation-time)) where they say you need to put

```
#ifndef test1
    #define test1 0 
#endif
```

But i have a lot of those and i would prefer not to add 40 lines of definition code.
Will compilation command -D flag take priority over my hard definition without the if clause?

EDIT : So i just tested it (which i should have done anyway before asking...) and compiler -D flag does not take priority over my own definition and just pulls out a warning . So any way for it to take priority and always use the compiler flags without passing through ifndef clauses?

Comment: generally we use `#ifdef` with the assumption that by default the values are undefined, so there is no need to add a lot of `#define` directives in the first place, they are implicitly unset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-D` effectively adds a `#define` at the beginning, before reading the input. So it would be just like adding an additional `#define` in your source code, which would naturally produce an error (or warning) about redefining the macro.

If you want to avoid that error, use the `#ifndef` idiom, just like everyone else does.

Comment: just wanted to verify if there was another way to do it which bypassed the `#ifndef` usage! 
thanks for the answer